# Create SObject metadata in unit test

Tags: unit-test, managed-package

We are using sobject settings in our package. Is it possible to create metadata sobject in the unit test?

Comment: sobject settings? do you mean custom metadata types?

Comment: Nope, create sobject that doesn't exist in the system.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible. Unit tests are run in as context of current environment status (with recent changes during deployment), but they do not allow to make changes into model (at least for now). It might be a good reason to revisit unit tests in order to cover smaller pieces of logic instead of whole process, that includes data model changes. Apex Stub API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_StubProvider.htm) could also help in that

Comment: @kurunve that seems like a good answer to this question - would you like to post an answer?